# Weak convergence random of vectors implies weak convergence of their coordinates

Tags: probability-theory

Is it true that if random vectors $X_{n} \xrightarrow{d}X$ then the coordinates $X_{n,i} \xrightarrow{d}X_{i}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $X_{n} \xrightarrow{d}X$ implies $f(X_{n}) \xrightarrow{d}f(X)$  for any continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R^{n}$.